# Powershell issue with a defined variable

Tags: powershell

I am pretty new to powershell and have a code that I found. I had it working but now it is no longer working. I didn't change anything with the variable so I am not sure what is going on. Here is a link to a Screenshot of the code and error. Please let me know if you need any other information

https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0q84.jpg

Thank you!

```bsh
Import-Module activedirectory
 
$ADUsers = Import-csv 'C:\Users\Desktop\Powershell files\EM-mis-new-AD.csv'

foreach ($User in $ADUsers)
{
    $Username   = $User.username
    $Password   = $User.password
    $Firstname  = $User.firstname
    $Lastname   = $User.lastname
    $OU         = $User.ou 
    $Password   = $User.Password
    
    if (Get-ADUser -F {SamAccountName -eq $Username})
    {
         Write-Warning "A user account with username $Username already exist in Active Directory."
    }
    else
    {
        New-ADUser `
            -SamAccountName $Username `
            -UserPrincipalName "$Username@Mydomain" `
            -Name "$Firstname $Lastname" `
            -GivenName $Firstname `
            -Surname $Lastname `
            -Enabled $True `
            -DisplayName "$Firstname, $Lastname" `
            -Path $OU `
            -AccountPassword (convertto-securestring $Password -AsPlainText -Force) -ChangePasswordAtLogon $True
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Get-ADUser : Variable: 'Username' found in expression: $Username is not defined.
At C:\Users\jcarnovale\Desktop\Testing if.ps1:22 char:6
    if (Get-ADUser -F {SamAccountName -eq $Username})
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADUser], ArgumentException
    FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUse
```

Comment: Please post the actual code you need help with (instead of a screenshot of it)

Comment: I have edited the post to have the code and error code in it

Comment: Try `Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$Username'"`

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to check that you have a good username before proceeding in the script, like:

```
$Username   = $User.username
...
if(!$Username) {
   throw "Username was empty!"
}
```

Also, try changing the Get-ADUser filter to use a string:

```
if (Get-ADUser -F "SamAccountName -eq $Username")
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show us anything of the imported CSV file itself and I think the main problem is in there.

`Import-Csv` by default expects the comma (`,`) to be used as delimiter character. If that is not the case in your file, you need to add parameter `-Delimiter` followed by the character that is used as separator in your file (like `-Delimiter ';'` if your file uses the semicolon).
Please check that first, so the Import-Csv cmdlet can parse the file correctly.

Next, it could be that there are empty values in the `username` column and if so, the code should skip these rows.

Also, as commented, the `-Filter` parameter needs a double-quoted **string** *`"Property -eq 'something'"`* in which a variable like $username is expanded,  instead of a scriptblock *`{..}`*

Finally, I'd recommend using [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) on cmdlets that take many properties instead of using backticks.

Try

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

# this defaults to csv fields delimited by a comma. If your CSV file uses a different 
# character, then add parameter '-Delimiter' followed by the actual character
$ADUsers = Import-Csv -Path 'C:\Users\Desktop\Powershell files\EM-mis-new-AD.csv'

# the Where-Object clause is just a precaution to omit records that have no username value
$ADUsers | Where-Object { $_.username -match '\S'} | ForEach-Object {
    $Username = $_.username
    if (Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$Username'" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
        Write-Warning "A user account with SamAccountName '$Username' already exist in Active Directory."
    }
    else {
        $Firstname  = $_.firstname
        $Lastname   = $_.lastname

        # use splatting on cmdlets that use a lot of parameters
        $userParams = @{
            SamAccountName        = $Username
            UserPrincipalName     = "$Username@Mydomain.com"
            Name                  = "$Firstname $Lastname"
            GivenName             = $Firstname
            Surname               = $Lastname
            Enabled               = $true
            DisplayName           = "$Firstname, $Lastname"
            Path                  = $_.ou
            AccountPassword       = (ConvertTo-SecureString $_.Password -AsPlainText -Force)
            ChangePasswordAtLogon = $true
        }
        # create the user and report back
        New-ADUser @userParams

        Write-Host "Created new user '$Username' with initial password: $($_.Password)"
    }
}
```